# after_commit not getting called after update_all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have after_commit setup as folllows.

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_commit { Rails.logger.info ("commit here") }

  # ...
end
```

I am then wrapping update_all, which doesn't fire a callback, inside a transaction, which is supposed to fire a callback.

```
MyModel.transaction do
  MyModel.update_all(col: 'awesome')
end
```

Why isn't the after_commit being fired?  I don't see "commit here" in my logs.  It works for destroy just fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The way `after_commit` works is that whenever a record is saved it gets added to a list of records. When the transaction gets committed, rails iterates over that list calling the after commit hooks on each one.

When you do `update_all` the instances aren't saved individually (since they aren't actually loaded at all - rails doesn't actually know which rows were updated) and so they don't get added to the list that power `after_commit`.

`destroy_all` is different because it does actually load all the instances and delete them one by one, firing all callbacks. You'd observe similar behaviour to `update_all` if you used `delete_all`

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate.  You think that after_commit would fire *after* it did a *COMMIT*.  Thanks.

Comment: @FrederickCheung I don't know if that's the case any more I called `destroy_all` from console the `after_commit` callback doesn't fire at all. even though the call was made individually on every object of the model

Comment: What happens in case of model.update instead of model.save?